# How to handle components with different routes in react js

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have build an react app with 3pages Page1,Page2,Page3 and have Navbar and Sidebar component. And using react-router v6 for rendering components.

I want the Navbar component on all of the pages and Sidebar on only page3, i am able to render navbar on all the pages but how i can show only sidebar on the page3?????

Remember not to use Sidebar component direct in the page3.

Here is code and picture:

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./pages/page1/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/page2/Page2";
import Page3 from "./pages/page3/Page3";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
        <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
        <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: you can import `SideBar` to `Page3` instead to adding as a child of `Router` which will be shown on all the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass multiple components to one `Route` and show them in that path, you can put those components in an array and give this array to the `element` prop in `<Route/>`.

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./pages/page1/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/page2/Page2";
import Page3 from "./pages/page3/Page3";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
        <Route path="/page2" element={[<Page2/>,<Sidebar/>]} />
        <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

With this, in the `/page2` URL, you can access both components and then you can layout them

Answer (score 4):

The `element` takes any valid JSX as a value. In RRDv6 it's common to use wrapper components to render multiple components or provide additional logic/UI you want only on specific routes. In this case you can use a React `Fragment` to wrap the `Sidebar` and `Page3` components.

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./pages/page1/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/page2/Page2";
import Page3 from "./pages/page3/Page3";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./components/sidebar/Sidebar";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
        <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
        <Route
          path="/page3"
          element={(
            <>
              <Sidebar />
              <Page3 />
            </>
          )}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

A more common approach would be to abstract this into a layout wrapper component that can wrap any routed component and additionally render a sidebar. This is helpful when you want to do the above in more than one place and you want to reduce code duplication (*i.e. make the code more **DRY***). Nested `Route` components are rendered into an `Outlet`.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const SidebarLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Sidebar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

...

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./pages/page1/Page1";
import Page2 from "./pages/page2/Page2";
import Page3 from "./pages/page3/Page3";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar";
import SidebarLayout from "./components/sidebar/SidebarLayout";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
        <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
        <Route element={<SidebarLayout />}>
          <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```